# Procedimiento almacenado. PHP. Error # 1221: uso incorrecto de UNION y LIMIT

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy realizando un procedimiento almacenado y obtengo el siguiente error:

> ## 1221: uso incorrecto de UNION y LIMIT

Te dejo el código:

Realmente agradecería cualquier ayuda que pueda proporcionar.

```
IF (_flagContar=1) THEN

        SELECT
            COUNT(*) AS total
        FROM
        (
        SELECT persona FROM mae_persona WHERE numerodocumento=_buscar LIMIT 50
        UNION
        SELECT persona FROM mae_persona WHERE nombrecompleto LIKE CONCAT(_buscar,'%') LIMIT 50) AS q;

ELSE
        SET @rownum=0;

            SELECT 
                @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS rownum,
                persona,nombrecompleto,direccion,email          
            FROM 
            (
                SELECT 
                    persona,nombrecompleto,direccion,email
                FROM
                (                   
                SELECT persona,nombrecompleto,direccion,email 
                FROM mae_persona WHERE numerodocumento=_buscar LIMIT 50
                UNION
                SELECT persona,nombrecompleto,direccion,email 
                FROM mae_persona WHERE nombrecompleto LIKE CONCAT(_buscar,'%') order by nombrecompleto LIMIT 50) AS q
            ) AS p          
        HAVING rownum > _reg_por_pag * (_pagina-1)
        AND rownum <= _reg_por_pag * _pagina
        ORDER BY rownum;
  END IF;
END ;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay poner la sentencia de la consulta con LIMIT dentro de paréntesis y después utilizar UNION:

```
(SELECT persona FROM mae_persona WHERE numerodocumento=_buscar LIMIT 50)

UNION

(SELECT persona FROM mae_persona WHERE nombrecompleto LIKE CONCAT(_buscar,'%') LIMIT 50) AS q
```

Y en la parte del else

```
(SELECT persona,nombrecompleto,direccion,email 
            FROM mae_persona WHERE numerodocumento=_buscar LIMIT 50)
UNION

(SELECT persona,nombrecompleto,direccion,email 
            FROM mae_persona WHERE nombrecompleto LIKE CONCAT(_buscar,'%') order by nombrecompleto LIMIT 50) AS q
```

Aquí hay un link a la documentación:
[MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)

Comment: ya hice eso con los paréntesis y múltiples combinaciones posibles con los paréntesis y nada, help me

Comment: Analiza tus consultas por separado e identifica en qué parte se da el error, en cuál de las subconsultas o en cuáles. Debe de haber un paréntesis que falte.